# "Пожалуйста" в вопросительных предложениях

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, этикет

В последнее время я стал часто слышать подобные конструкции:

1. Можно, пожалуйста, <...>?
2. Вы не могли бы <...>, пожалуйста?

По мне так оба варианта звучат не очень, хотя второй и не настолько катастрофически провинциален, как первый. Возможно, оттого, что он маскируется под

2'. Вы не могли бы <...>? Пожалуйста!

Употребление "пожалуйста" в вопросительных предложениях как-то регламентируется языковыми нормами?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу! И мне интересно, что скажут специалисты. По-моему, это из английского пришло. Мне это тоже не нравится. Хотя, возможно, это было в языке и раньше, тогда придётся признать это нормальным. Не хотелось бы, чтобы так оказалось.

Comment: Я слышал такие варианты употребления ещё до того, как заимствования из английского стали массовыми. Но они действительно в точности повторяют стандартную конструкцию "Could you please <...>?", что сегодня приводит к некоторой их легитимации в головах тех, кто постоянно имеет дело с английским. Для английского уха повелительное наклонение звучит грубовато, отсюда и всевозможные "I'm wondering if you could..." и пр.

Comment: *...что сегодня приводит к некоторой их легитимации в головах тех, кто постоянно имеет дело с английским.* Я постоянно имею дело с английским, но ни к какой легитимации это не приводит для меня. :)) Я считаю, что в языке надо по возможности избегать заимствований, и ненавижу всякие кейсы (в смысле случаев), локации, депозиты и тому подобные нелепые слова. Ту же "легитимацию" нельзя заменить "узаконением" в данном случае? Я спрашиваю, п. ч. не привык к этому слову, и мне сложно судить самому.

Comment: Для Вас не приводит как раз потому, что Вы сознательно стараетесь избегать заимствований ;)

Comment: Именно так - неестественным образом - употребляют слово "пожалуйста" эммигранты второго поколения (ЛУРы): https://books.google.co.il/books?id=cPZzCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=QDskTA0bep&sig=XKFf2-iMP3hQ-GQU8VXNBPQ5ZGk&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXuJPUs-bVAhUIMZoKHcDRD1MQ6AEIRzAF#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false

Comment: Не очень понятно, как можно услышать (о 2-м примере речь) запятую, а не тчк, или тчк/зпт? И как можно обсуждать столь тонкие моменты на схемах? Дефицит полноценных законченных фраз?

Answer (score 2):

"Пожалуйста" употребляется, ТОЛЬКО если предложение содержит просьбу, например: "Передайте, пожалуйста..." В вопросительных предложениях употребляться не может, так как вопрос теряет свой смысл как вопрос.

Comment: *"Пожалуйста" употребляется, ТОЛЬКО если предложение содержит просьбу*  — Странно, когда носители языка сами так думают или голосуют за такое мнение. [Здесь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0) можно посмотреть, в каких ещё случаях употребляется "пожалуйста".