# Он был так убедителен, что ей показалось естественным принять его деловое предложение

Tags: синтаксис

Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, проверить - это придаточное образа действия и степени?

> Он был так убедителен, *что ей показалось естественным принять его
>   деловое предложение.*

Спасибо!

Comment: О корректности употребления слова-вставки в тексте вашего вопроса: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433702/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он был **так убедителен**, **что** ей показалось естественным принять его деловое предложение.

Это придаточное с двойным значением: **степени признака (в какой степени убедителен) и следствия.** Опорным словом является **краткое прилагательное *убедителен***.

Степень признака, обозначенного прилагательным, характеризуется через **ситуацию**, названную в придаточном. Связь местоименно-союзная (так...что, союз ЧТО со значением следствия).

Сравнить: Он был так осторожен, как бывают осторожны люди, находящиеся в опасности. Это придаточное только **степени**, связь местоименная (как...так).

Примечание. В СПП с придаточным **образа действия** опорным словом является **глагол**: Он поступил так, как ему советовали.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то не вижу тут **действия** и его **образа** :-) Вот **степень** убедительности была такова, что ей показалось естественным принять его деловое предложение.

Примечание. Есть группа придаточных, называемая "Придаточные образа действия и степени", но каждое отдельное придаточное является придаточным образа действия или придаточным степени, но не тем и другим одновременно.

Примеры:

> Наступление шло так, как было преду­смотрено в штабе (К. Симонов)

— здесь придаточное образа действия.

> Старушке столько же хотелось повторить свой рассказ, сколько мне его слушать (А. Герцен)

— здесь  придаточное степени.